# substring extraction in HQL

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

There's a URL field in my Hive DB that is of string type with this specific pattern:

> /Cats-g294078-o303631-Maine_Coon_and_Tabby.html

and I would like to extract the two Cat "types" near the end of the string, with the result being something like:

> mainecoontabby

Basically, I'd like to only extract - as one lowercase string - the Cat "types" which are always separated by '_ and _', preceded by '-', and followed by '.html'.

Is there a simple way to do this in HQL? I know HQL has limited functionality, otherwise I'd be using regexp or substring or something like that.

Thanks,
Clark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution here...

```
LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTRING(catString, LOCATE('-', catString, 19)+1), '(_to_)|(\.html)|_', ''))
```

Interestingly, the following did NOT work... JJFord3, any idea why?

```
LOWER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(SUBSTRING(FL.url, LOCATE('-', FL.url, 19)+1), '[^(_to_)|(\.html)|_]', 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

HQL does have a `substr` function as cited here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions
It returns the piece of a string starting at a value until the end (or for a particular length)

I'd also utilize the function `locate` to determine the location of the '-' and '_' in the URL.

As long as there are always three dashes and three underscores this should be pretty straight forward.

Might need case statements to determine number of dashes and underscores otherwise.

Comment: Hey JJFord3, thanks for the tips - after some self-education I managed to finagle some operations together and get what I wanted. Exact answer posted below.